# How to remove Color/Style format from a variable

Tags: bash, colors

I am having a variable with Some words in Different color and Styles.
How can I remove the styles and print as a plain text. My Actual requirement is - when I do a word count. It counts the characters of styles also.

Example:

```
    RED=$(tput setaf 1) 
    NORMAL=$(tput sgr0) 
    BOLD=$(tput bold)

    string=$(printf "this ${RED}${BOLD}is${NORMAL} a test1\n")
    echo "$string" | wc -c
```

output:

```
    31
```

Actual count

```
printf "this is a test1\n" | wc -c
```

output

```
    16
```

How can I get actual count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping ANSI color codes from a string can be achieved by the extended globbing `extglob` feature of Bash like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob # Enable Bash Extended Globbing expressions

RED=$(tput setaf 1)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
BOLD=$(tput bold)

# This is how to add control characters without echoing in a subshell
string="this ${RED}${BOLD}is${NORMAL} a test1"$'\n'

printf 'Before stripping ANSI color codes:\n%s\ncontains %d characters\n\n' "$string" "${#string}"

# Use the extended globbing with string substitution
# to remove all ANSI control sequences from string
no_color_string="${string//$'\e'[\[(]*([0-9;])[@-n]/}"

printf 'After stripping ANSI color codes:\n%s\ncontains %d characters\n\n' "$no_color_string" "${#no_color_string}"
```

Output:

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1):

`tput` generates codes based on the terminal type. So as well as vt52/vt100/vtxx, it could work with other terminal types. It could for example generate html.

There is no equivalent ncurses package to strip them out and you can't predict the terminal type, so you can't perfectly strip that info out.

That said, your data is quite possibly VT, which uses escape codes, which you could strip away.
They are all in the form `\033XXXm` eg `\033[38;5;206m` which can easily be stripped away with `sed`.